# understanding IPrincipal in mvc

Tags: c#, security, iprincipal

I'm trying to understand the purpose of IPrincipal and IIdentity or just Principal objects in general.

From what I've been reading from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftx85f8x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). IIdentity describes the user that is authentication and any information about them.

and IPrincipal is the context in which the user was authenticated.

Am I correct about these two explanations? What's really throwing me off in the article is the "security context" for principal, I'm not sure I truly understand what that means.

I am a bit confused

Answer (score 0):

You have it in the very next sentence

> The principal object represents the security context under which code is running. Applications that implement role-based security grant rights based on the role associated with a principal object.

Technically, the `IPrincipal` adds roles on top of `IIdentity`. It does so by requiring the `IsInRole` method

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.isinrole(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.isinrole%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This is how roles are inspected by the client code and thus role-based security is established.

Comment: "Security context" is what I'm confused by

Comment: The mean "role based security" apparently.